# MySQL index on BIT column strange behaviour

Tags: mysql, index

Using MySQL 5.7

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `col2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index1` (`col1`,`col2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And with this rows:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `col1`, `col2`)
VALUES
    (1, 0, 1),
    (2, 0, 2),
    (3, 0, 3);
```

**query1** - I get no results for this query:

```
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE
col1 = '0' AND col2 IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Explain for this query:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    no matching row in const table
```

**query2** - But I do get results when I remove the single quotes for `0`:

```
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE
col1 = 0 AND col2 IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Explain for this query:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  test    NULL    ref index1  index1  2   const   3   50.00   Using where; Using index
```

**query3** - And most interesting is that I also get the expected results if I ignore the index:

```
SELECT * FROM test
USE INDEX() 
WHERE
col1 = '0' AND col2 IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Explain for this query:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  test    NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2   50.00   Using where
```

As far as I know there is no `CAST` or `CONVERT` to `BIT`, so this could explain why `col1 = '0'` could be a problem, but if I ignore the index then it works in both cases: `col1 = '0'` and `col1 = 0`

I know that adding an index on a `BIT` column would not make much sense since cardinality for this column is going to be quite low, but it could make sense when is a Multiple-Column index.

**Questions:**

- Why I get results when I ignore the index?
- Should I still declare Multiple-Column index when one of the columns is of type `BIT`? I would say yes, as long as you don't quote the values on the query :D

Comment: _A guess_:  The developers ignore `BIT` when looking at ways to improve the Optimizer.  _Workaround_:  Use `TINYINT UNSIGNED` instead of `BIT`.